# Concerning 'a change of variables'

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $f: (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto (F_1,\ldots,F_n)$
be a $k$-algebra endomorphism of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, where $F$ is a field and $n \geq 1$.

When one says that, *after a change of variables*, we can assume that $F_1,\ldots,F_n$ has a certain property, does one mean the following:

> There exists a $k$-algebra automorphism $g$ of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$,
>   such that $g(F_1),\ldots,g(F_n)$ has that certain property.

Please, is this correct?

I guess that my question is quite trivial, but I wish to be sure that I am not missing something. More precisely, I wish to be sure that we are talking about $g(F_i)=g(f(x_i))=(gf)(x_i)$ and not about $(fg)(x_i)$.

Thank you  very much!

Comment: First $f$, then $g$. So $(gf)(x_i) = g(f(x_i)) =g(F_i)$ would be fine.

Comment: Thank you. So what I thought is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This phrase is ambiguous and could have several meanings: it could refer to a composition of the form $gf$, or it could refer instead to $fg$, or it could refer to the conjugation $gfg^{-1}$, or it might even refer to something like $gfh$ where $g$ and $h$ are two automorphisms.  You'll have to figure out from context what meaning is intended (it should usually be clear in context).  Lacking any context, I would guess that the conjugation $gfg^{-1}$ is the most likely meaning.